# Install Groovy from Source failed on sbcl

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install groovy from source on my Beaglebone Black, Ubuntu 12.10. After following the instructions, I execute:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
```

And then I get the error:

```
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y sbcl]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sbcl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  sbcl-source sbcl-doc

E: Package 'sbcl' has no installation candidate
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y sbcl] failed
```

It seems that sbcl is not available. Does anyone know how to get around this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65757/install-groovy-from-source-failed-on-sbcl/) by [sgwhack](https://answers.ros.org/users/2844/sgwhack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-06-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you would like to try removing things that use lisp, you can do that by removing the roslisp package, and by commenting out the run_depend dependency in the ros_comm package.

---

Originally posted by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) with karma: 283 on 2013-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JetForMe](https://answers.ros.org/users/8636/jetforme/) on 2013-11-10**:
Could you explain precisely how to do this? I'm just getting started with ROS. Is the package to get rid of, in this case, just src/roslisp, and is the rundepend in src/ros_comm/package.xml?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2014-03-25**:
worked perfectly! I only had to rm'd src/roslisp and then removed the reference to roslisp in src/ros_comm/ross_comm/package.xml.